# Terminal - Rename file based on wildcard

Tags: bash

I have a scenario where I have two files in a folder:

> 1) Foo bar.pdf
>
> 2) Another File.pdf

I am merging both files into one. The resulting file must be named "Foo.pdf".

So the .sh file would contain the following function:

> Check if *.pdf contains "bar" //check all PDFs in the folder for the word "bar" in the filename.
>
> If TRUE ($value = "Foo.pdf") //extract "Foo" from filename
>
> mkfile = $value.pdf

Thus, I would end up with something like the following:

> (Directory 1)
>
> FILE 1: Foo Blah Blah 123.pdf
>
> FILE 2: Another File.pdf
>
> ...run script...
>
> FILE 3: **Foo.pdf** //created file

Hope that makes sense? Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to do, but what you need is `bash` parameter parsing: in a file path, `${FilePath%/*}` is the directory path, `${FilePath##*/}` is the file name and `[ "${FileName#*bar} != "SFileName" ]` tests for `bar` in the file name. You rename with `mv`, but any directory path in the old name must be present in the new (otherwise, the file will be renamed and moved to the current directory).

Comment: @AFH I have edited my question to make it a bit clearer. Thanks for your comment, it has has definitely given me a start.

Comment: Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: So you're trying to find all files with a particular substring in the middle of the name, and then rename those files so as to strip that substring out of their filenames. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
for FILE in *bar.pdf; do
    NEWNAME=$(echo $FILE | sed -En 's/(.*)bar.pdf/\1.pdf/p')
    mv $FILE $NEWNAME
done
```

Explanation: This uses `bash`'s for-loop syntax and shell globbing (wildcard-based filename matching) to process each file that ends in "bar.pdf". It takes the name of each file and sends it into `sed`. `sed` is told to remember the part of the filename before the "bar.pdf", and then replace the filename with the remembered part, with ".pdf" appended to the end. That new file name is stored as NEWNAME. Then `mv` is invoked to rename the file to its new name, and the loop continues to process the next file (if there are any more files matching *bar.pdf).

(Tested using macOS High Sierra 10.13.6's built-in `bash` and `sed`. Your system's tools may vary. I'm pretty sure the GNU `sed` in Linux uses different command-line options than the BSD-based `sed` in macOS, so check your local `sed` man page first.)